# Qt xml file issues with content above root node

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm having a difficult time with Qt DOM and the DTD of an XML file.
Let's say that we have an xml file like the one bellow.  The DTD is embedded into the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE notes [
  <!ELEMENT (note+)>
  <!ELEMENT note (to,from,heading,message)>
  <!ELEMENT to      (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT from    (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT message (#PCDATA)>
]>
<!-- modified w3schools example -->
<notes> 
   <note>
      <to>Megatron</to> 
      <from>Pele</from> 
      <heading>Match</heading> 
      <message>Make sure you bring the beer!</message> 
   </note>
</notes>
```

How do I read the DTD from the file and then write it back to the same file after editing the DOM tree?

The problem I'm having is that if I read the xml file I only get the root node <notes> and its contents into a dom tree.  Thus, when I write my dom tree back to the file, everything above the dom tree is lost!  How can I read that content and write it back to the file along with the modified dom tree?

I'm using Qt 4.7 and C++.

**EDIT 1 (BASED ON POSTS):**

This is how I parse the file and navigate the dom tree.

```
QDomDocument notes;
if( !notes.setContent(&file) ){
    file.close();                                          
    return -1;
}
file.close();                                             

//Get root element.  
//.documentElement() skips proc instr and DTD!
QDomElement re = notes.documentElement();              
if( re.tagName() != "notes"){                          
    qerr << "Err: Root element is not NOTES." << endl;
    return -1;
}

nNote = re.firstChild();
while( !nNote.isNull() )
{
    QDomElement eNote = nNote.toElement();        
    if( !eNote.isNull() && eNote.tagName() == "note" ){
        //some work...
    }
    nNote = nNote.nextSibling();
}
```

Note that this way does not allow me to get a handle on nodes above <notes>... things like proc instr and DTD nodes.  When I write (QDomDocument notes) back to file the DTD that was in the file gets deleted.

**EDIT 2 (BASED ON POSTS):**

```
//Based on QDomDocument notes;
qout << notes.doctype() << endl;        //Only prints <!DOCTYPE notes
QDomDocumentType dt = notes.doctype();  
qout << "(QDomDocumentType dt) has child nodes: " << dt.hasChildNodes() <<endl; //False

QDomNodeList children = notes.childNodes();
for ( int i=0; i < children.count(); ++i ) {
   QDomNode child = children.at( i );
   //Only proc & element nodes show! DTD node does not exist according to this loop.
   qout << "Type of node is: " << child.nodeType() << endl; 
   qout << "Node is DTD: " << child.isDocumentType() << endl;  //False.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think the answer to my question is that Qt is not capable of dealing with an internal DTD.  It should be... but it seems it is not.

Answer (score 0):

How do you read the file and write it back?

For the processing instructions and the comment, you can iterate over QDomDocument::childNodes() to get all top-level nodes (including the root element).

The DTD can be accessed via QDomDocument::docType(). You can create a new QDomDocument with a given doc type (it seems you would have to keep the QDomDocumentType object from the original document around) using the QDomDocument( const QDomDocumentType& ) constructor.

**Edit:**

Here's how to iterate over top-level nodes (Note that QDomDocument is QDomNode itself):

```
QDomDocument doc;
...
QDomNodeList children = doc.childNodes();
for ( int i=0; i < children.count(); ++i ) {
    QDomNode child = children.at( i );
    //do something with child...
}
```

Comment: I added the info you asked for.  I don't see how I can iterate over the child nodes to get top-level nodes.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it with your code snippet but it does not work.  It can see proc instruction node now but still... dtd node remains invisible to Qt dom.  I can't get a handle on the dtd node...  Also, .doctype() only returns ( <!DOCTYPE notes ) but the dtd definition that goes with it is lost.

Comment: Does the doctype object have child nodes? It's also a dom node.

Comment: Frank, it does not have child nodes.  Code to show this is above.